# ff Package in R: is "no diskspace" error a permissions issue?

Tags: r, diskspace, ff

I'm using the `ff` package in RStudio, which is running on a Windows server in my department.  I'm using it to work with some large datasets, which I'm also storing on a network drive. I have confirmed that I have full read/write access to the drive in Windows, but when I use any functions in the `ff` package that directly writes a flat file to disk (such as `ff()` or `as.ff()` ), I get a "no diskspace" error.

However, if I write the data to another drive and then move it over to the network drive using `pattern()` it works fine. I only have this issue with the `ff` package. Other functions from `base` such as `save()` and `write.csv()` work fine.  Is there a permissions issue that is specific to the `ff` package? I've included a minimal working example below.

```
> library(ff)
>
> # Set ff temporary directory to Network Drive
> options(fftempdir = "\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/")
>
> test <- 1:10
> test.ff <- ff(test)
Error in ff(test) : no diskspace
>
> # But if I write it to another drive and then move it over, it works fine
>
> # Set the ff temporary directory to another drive
> options(fftempdir = "R:/analysis/tmp/")
> test.ff <- ff(test)
>
> physical(test.ff)$filename
[1] "R:/analysis/tmp/ff32081b6926e5.ff"
>
> pattern(test.ff) <- "\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/"
>
> physical(test.ff)$filename
[1] "\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/3208208747f3.ff"
```

And here is the software version information for R:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: The message says that your diskspace is full. Is your disk full? Does save(test, file = "\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/test.RData") work or does it also fail because of your disk being full?

Comment: @jwijffels No, the disk is not full. There is ~500GB available. `save(test, file="\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/test.RData")` and `write.csv(test, file=\\\\fs01/analysis/tmp/test.csv")` both work fine, as does creating the file elsewhere and moving it over using `pattern( )`

Comment: I have worked with a similar setup using a network drive to store ff files but never encountered that problem. Only when my drive was full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here for future reference. We believe there is some kind of issue with resolving the server address within the ff sourcecode, maybe a bug.
We ran into the exact same issue as you did - it was resolved by setting up a network drive named "x" for the remote location and then using the address

```
x:/yourfolder
```

instead of

```
\\servername/yourfolder
```

We also noticed that the ff file on disk is allocated nonetheless there is the error "no diskspace" when using something like

```
ff.test <- ff(vmode="double",filename="\\servername/youfolder/ff.test",dim=c(1000,1000))
```

and after sending the same line again, the ff object is created without errors.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I ended up stumbling upon this as well, but only through much trial and error.